# Derivative of the function $\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{2^{x+1}}{1+4^x}\Big)$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

> Find y' if $y=\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{2^{x+1}}{1+4^x}\Big)$

In my reference $y'$ is given as $\frac{2^{x+1}\log2}{(1+4^x)}$. But is it a complete solution ?

**Attempt 1**

Let $2^x=\tan\alpha$
$$
\begin{align}
y=\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}\Big)=\sin^{-1}(\sin2\alpha)&\implies \sin y=\sin2\alpha=\sin\big(2\tan^{-1}2^x\big)\\
&\implies y=n\pi+(-1)^n(2\tan^{-1}2^x)
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
y'&=\pm\frac{2.2^x.\log2}{1+4^x}=\pm\frac{2^{x+1}.\log2}{1+4^x}\\
&=\color{blue}{\begin{cases}
\frac{2^{x+1}.\log2}{1+4^x}\text{ if }-n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq2\tan^{-1}2^x\leq -n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\\
-\frac{2^{x+1}.\log2}{1+4^x}\text{ if }n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq2\tan^{-1}2^x\leq n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}}
\end{align}
$$
**Attempt 2**

$$
\begin{align}
y'&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(2^{x+1})^2}{(1+4^x)^2}}}.\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2^{x+1}}{1+4^x}\\
&=\frac{1+4^x}{\sqrt{1+4^{2x}+2.4^x-4^x.4}}.\frac{(1+4^x)\frac{d}{dx}2^{x+1}-2^{x+1}\frac{d}{dx}(1+4^x)}{(1+4^x)^2}\\
&=\frac{(1+4^x).2^{x+1}.\log2-2^{x+1}.4^x.\log2.2}{\sqrt{1+4^{2x}-2.4^x}.(1+4^x)}\\&=\frac{2^{x+1}\log2\big[1+4^x-2.4^x\big]}{\sqrt{(1-4^x)^2}.(1+4^x)}\\&=\frac{2^{x+1}\log2\big[1-4^x\big]}{|{(1-4^x)}|.(1+4^x)}\\
&=\color{blue}{\begin{cases}\frac{2^{x+1}\log2}{(1+4^x)}\text{ if }1>4^x>0\\
-\frac{2^{x+1}\log2}{(1+4^x)}\text{ if }1<4^x
\end{cases}}
\end{align}
$$
In both my attempts i am getting both +ve and -ve solutions. Is it the right way to find the derivative?

And how do I connect the domain for each cases in attempt 1 and attempt 2 ?

Comment: Holy cow. Is this an exercise from a book? Anyway, you may also try to take the sine on both sides and then use implicit differentiation.  The neat thing is that $2^{x+1}$ and $1+4^x$ relate very nice in a right triangle. That is, through the Pythagorean theorem, the adjacent turns out to be $1-4^x$ (a little algebra)

Comment: @imranfat could u pls elaborate a bit on how to follow this ?.. Could u pls comment on the domain of the $y'$ in both my attempts ?.. and is there both +ve and -ve solutions to the problem ?

Comment: I can't find error...I checked it by desmos. Actually it is normal for analysis to have $\vert$(somethings)$\vert$.

Comment: @imranfat thanx. so u mean final answer in both my attempts are correct right ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764431/solving-arcsin-left2x-sqrt1-x2-right-2-arcsin-x  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979149/tan-frac12-sin-1-2x-1-x2-frac12-cos-1-1-y2-1

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thnks for the help. could u pls confirm final answer in both my attempts are correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The trickiest part is the ^2 part let me know if you do not follow that step. I do not know how to use the fancy formatting so I had to write it out.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kNvI.jpg)

Comment: thanx. but how can it be different from my **Attempt 2** ?

Comment: I believe you simplified the inverse of ONLY Sin wrong. You can't bring in other items into the square root that easy without simplifying other things. Everything on the right side is correct, the left side is incorrect.

Comment: srry i could not follow u. could u pls mention which step seems wrong ?. are u saying the final answer $\pm\frac{2^{x+1}.\log2}{1+4^x}$ is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sin^{-1} \Big(\frac{2^{x+1}}{1+4^x}\Big)$$ the right side of the equation will be called $b$ it will help later. Take sine of both sides and the derivative $$\cos(y) y' =\frac{ln(2)2^{x+1}}{4^x+1}-\frac{ln(4) 4^x 2^{x+1}}{(4^x+1)^2}$$ the right side of the equation will be called $b'$ so $$ y' cos(y)=b'$$ divide both sides by cosine $$y'=\frac{b'}{\cos(y)}$$ substitute $y$ for $b$ and you have $$y'=\frac{b'}{cos(b)}$$

Comment: thanx. this method is fine but i dont think it addresses my actual problem with the final answers.

Answer (score 0):

$y = arcsin(\frac{2^{x+1}}{1+4^x})\\\implies y = arcsin (\frac{2.2^x}{1+(2^x)^2})$

consider $y = arcsin(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$

here let $x =  tan(\theta) \implies \theta = arctan(x)$

$y= arcsin(\frac{2tan(\theta)}{1+ tan^2(\theta)}) = arcsin(sin(2\theta)) = 2\theta = 2arctan(x)$

so in your given question, $y = arcsin(\frac{2^{x+1}}{1+4^x}) = 2arctan(2^x) $

differentiate wrt x ;

$y' = \frac{2^{x+1}ln(2)}{1+4^x}$

Comment: $\sin^{-1}(\sin 2\theta)=2\theta$ only if $2\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so i think doing that is just incomplete.